# "nohup python3 .. &" ends once I disconnect from a server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, debian, background-process, nohup

This command

```
nohup python3 main.py > my_log.log 2>&1 &
```

will end once I disconnect from a server.  That is, if I disconnect and then connect 10 seconds later, the task, or a job, will be gone.

However, if I stay on a server, it continues to work as long as it needs, with no problem.

Why? How to make it work in background even after I disconnect?

It's an AWS Debian server.

Comment: Your command looks fine to me. What does your script do? Why do you think it's not running when you connect back?

Comment: @Paolo the scripts works fine on its own. I see that it's not working because "jobs -l" won't show anything running

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` only disconnects your code from the current terminal session, which will end when you exist from the server. You either have to use `disown`:

```
nohup python3 main.py > my_log.log 2>&1 & disown
```

or best way is to run your script in `tmux` or `screen` sessions. If you use `tmux` or `screen` you can always login back to your server, and get beck to your program.

Comment: That's wrong. `You either have to use disown:` -> I don't have to because I've used the command in my question plenty of times with other server provides and it's always worked.